# Android Studio: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dex

I am getting the non-zero exit value 1 while running the application in Android Studio. I tried all of the ways and can't fix it. I am using Windows7 32 bit and 4GB RAM. Any help will be much appreciated. I am struck up with this problem for last 2 days.

Below is the stacktrace output:

```
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList
:app:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 55 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1194)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$3.call(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:151)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$5$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$5$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:90)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
... 61 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
... 68 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 51.236 secs
```

Also below is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jdu.app"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 11
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        moduleName "values"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    //jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "3500m"
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':applib')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//compile  fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-palette.jar')
compile files('libs/okhttp-2.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-1.7.0.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.6-kinesis.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.7-core.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.7-ddb-mapper.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.7-ddb.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.7-s3.jar')
}
```

Comment: did you try to to "Build"-> "Clean Project" and then go to "Build" -> "Rebuild Project"?

Comment: Yes, lot of times. Tried even system restart, uninstall/install Android studio.

Comment: These links might help you. [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1) [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957412/why-java-exe-exit-with-value-1-in-android-studio)

Comment: I tried those links. Nothing working.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Let me know how you have resolved above issue. @gunaa

Comment: I resolved it. 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 is the common error code which Studio showing for various problem. Main thing is something wrong in the code. Analyzing the full error message in the console will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the solution was to close Android Studio and kill the java processs, which was very big . After this, my project runs normally.

Answer (score 1):

I just pressed on Clean PROJECT and worked for me ,thanks Ahmed Abdi

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

1) Try to clean Project (Build > Clean)

2) Try to Rebuild Project (Build > Rebuild)

**Solution 2**

This can also happen due to less Ram, close studio and then kill all Java Process and the restart Android studio

**Solution3**

If none of the above work then try this

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Add this to your gradle build in android {} it should work.